# How can you un-revoke PGP key in GPG?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

Whilst playing with GPG (and trying to figure out a safe way to store my revocation cert so nobody else could use it), I accidentally revoked my PGP key.

The revocation was only local; *not* sent to a keyserver, so I was sure there would be a way to un-revoke it... but I couldn't find anything. Even deleting the key and re-importing it didn't help; it still showed as revoked. In the end I deleted my entire keyring and re-imported everything, which worked. But there must be a better way...

So; how do you *un-revoke* a PGP key in GPG?

Also, where is the revocation stored, and why wasn't it deleted when I deleted the key from my keyring?

In case it makes any difference, I'm using GPG on OS X with the [GPGTools](https://gpgtools.org/) package.

Comment: http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2007-April/030726.html?

Comment: @iWizardPro thanks, I'd actually come across that, but I don't seem to have (or be able to find) the `gpgsplit` utility. Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you running? My gpgsplit is located at /usr/bin/gpgsplit for Ubuntu.

Comment: OS X, with GPGTools (https://gpgtools.org). my `gpg2` is at `/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2` (linked from `/usr/local/bin/gpg2`) but I can find no trace of `gpgsplit`. I guess it would be possible to do the process from Ubuntu, but by that point deleting and restoring my keychain is probably actually the easier option... Do you know why (and where) the revokation is kept after I delete the keypair itself?

Comment: [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)'s GnuPG brings `gpgslit`. You can install the package using `brew install gnupg`.

Comment: Thanks @JensErat. I actually found a simpler way (see my answer below), but that's good to know in case I need `gpgsplit` in the future.

Comment: (A note for myself.) Export the public/secret key blocks; clear the saved keys; from the both blocks delete a _signature packet_ (`0x2`) whose `signatureType` is `0x20` (_key revocation signature_); import them. `gpg`, `gpgsplit` and `cat` are needed.

Comment: @КонстантинВан that sounds interesting, maybe you'd like to go into more specifics in an answer?

Comment: @Caesar No, it’s just my summary of [the “Un-revoking a key pair” above](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2007-April/030726.html).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It turns out that it *is* possible (and relatively simple) to delete and re-import the key, provided that it is on a keyserver (and provided that the revocation has not been sent to the keyserver, of course).

This is what I found to work (`THEKEYID` is the short ID of the key):

1. Delete the public key as follows (the `--expert` option allows the public key to be deleted whilst the private key is kept) :

   ```
   gpg --expert --delete-key THEKEYID
   ```
2. Confirm by pressing:

   ```
   y
   ```
3. Fetch the public key again from a keyserver:

   ```
   gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys THEKEYID
   ```

Done!

Presumably this could also be done from a local (pre-revocation) backup of the public key, using `gpg --import public.key` instead of the third command.

Simply deleting the entire key (public and private) from the GPG Keychain Access GUI, and then restoring from a backup, did not work - I don't know why.

Comment: You probably have to use the 'trust' command within gpg to make the public key usable again.see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184947/how-to-import-secret-gpg-key-copied-from-one-machine-to-another#comment308499_184952

Answer (score 2):

A process to un-revoke your local revoked key, without implying any key server, has been shared in 2007 by *David Shaw* in [a post on the official mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2007-April/030724.html).

It goes as follows (I suggest you to make a backup of your `~/.gnupg` before going forward):

> 1. Export the public key into a file.
>
>    ```
>    gpg --export (thekey) > mykey.gpg
>    ```
> 2. Split it into parts:
>
>    ```
>    gpgsplit mykey.gpg
>    ```
>
>    This breaks the key into multiple files with names like
>
>    ```
>    "000001-006.public_key".
>    ```
> 3. Figure out which packet is the revocation. It's likely to be "000002-002.sig", but make sure with:
>
>    ```
>    gpg --list-packets 000002-002.sig
>    ```
>
>    That will show information about the packet.  If the sigclass is set to 0x20, that's the revocation. **Delete that file.**
> 4. Put the key back together again:
>
>    ```
>    cat 0000* > myfixedkey.gpg
>    ```
> 5. Remove the old key:
>
>    ```
>    gpg --expert --delete-key (thekey)
>    ```
>
>    You need --expert here so GPG will let you delete the public key when a private key is still around.
> 6. Import the new key:
>
>    ```
>    gpg --import myfixedkey.gpg
>    ```

Please note that, obviously, revocation certificates published on a keyserver cannot be un-revoked.