# Why has my gpg key been revoked (should I be concerned)?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I've been using my public/private key pair for multiple years on my own machine for local purposes only and I've experienced the yearly expiration.

However, this time (around the time my key usually expires) gpg says:

```
gpg2 --list-keys
/home/user/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2016-11-22 [SC] [widerrufen: 2016-11-25]
      KEY123456789
uid        [ widerrufen] My Name (Me) <my.name@mail.com>
```

I'm 100% sure I didn't revoke my key. Since my gpg version is localized and says "widerrufen", which should translate to "revoked", I tried expiring it nonetheless (via `gpg --edit-key` and subsequently `expire` and `1y`), but to no avail:

```
gpg: Beglaubigung fehlgeschlagen: Verarbeitung wurde abgebrochen
gpg: make_keysig_packet failed: Verarbeitung wurde abgebrochen
```

Which should translate to

```
gpg: Authentication failed: Processing aborted
gpg: make_keysig_packet failed: Processing aborted
```

Also I'm confused why it says, that it has been revoked on 2016-11-25. Is this an old key? Is it possible that my regular key has been removed from the key-ring without me noticing?

I read in [Un-revoke PGP key](https://superuser.com/questions/608336/un-revoke-pgp-key) that I should be able to reimport my key. However, I'm concerned that my system has been compromised, as I'm not able to explain why my key got revoked in the first place.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Can you `gpg –edit-key` this key and set a new expiration date?

Comment: @harrymc No, that's what I meant with `I tried expiring it`. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Are you requesting speculation on how your key came to be revoked?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings Yes, that's my question and if there would be any other way of revocation, like if the expiry date went on for too long. And if I should be concerned about it being revoked without me noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I'm confused why it says, that it has been revoked on 2016-11-25.

The revoked date reflects the date the revocation certificate was generated, not the date the revocation was applied to the key.

As far as how it happened, all that can be certain is the revocation certificate used was not the one automatically generated at the time of key creation - this is evidenced by the fact the key creation time and revocation date are not identical:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-11-22 [SC] [widerrufen: 2016-11-25]
```

3 days after the key was created, you (or, if the key had no password protection, possibly someone else with access to your computer) generated a revocation certificate using `gpg --gen-revoke name`. Do you recall generating this revocation certificate? If so, do you remember where you stored it?

Unless you have an encrypted home directory, anyone with access to your computer could import the revocation certificate to your keyring.

> Is this an old key? Is it possible that my regular key has been removed from the key-ring without me noticing?

Sure, that's possible. If you want to make sure this is the right key, try verifying some signature you made with it prior to revocation.

Comment: Yes, I remember generating the certificate. It's stored in my home dir. It might be possible, that I created it 3 days later. I also grepped through my history for gpg, but couldn't find any command before I already noticed that my key has been revoked.

Comment: All it takes to revoke a key is to import the revocation certificate, which is done the same as importing a public key using the `--import` command. `gpg --import filename` would import the revocation certificate named `filename` causing the key to become revoked. Also the command `gpg --import *` would import the revocation and anything else in the active directory. Another user of the same computer could also import the certificate to your keyring by telling their gpg to use your keyring.

Comment: It's still mindboggling to me, since I'm the only user of this machine. Anyways, I guess I'm going to reinstall my OS (with encrypting my home dir this time), create a new key pair, and reinit my password store with the new pair.

Comment: If you are the only user of that machine I would consider it far more likely you imported the revocation by mistake. I don't know which OS you're using, but if it's linux I suggest looking through your .bash_history file for all occurrences of `--import` to see if you can find a command which may have imported it.

Comment: Unfortunately my bash history is only 2000 entrys long -_-. So I guess I'll have to live with the uncertainty how it happened. Thank you very much for your help!